# Laravel Model Events - I'm a bit confused about where they're meant to go

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So the way I see it is that a good Laravel application should be very model- and event-driven.

I have a Model called `Article`. I wish to send email alerts when the following events happen:

- When an Article is created
- When an Article is updated
- When an Article is deleted

[The docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events) say I can use Model Events and register them within the `boot()` function of `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`.

But this is confusing me because...

- What happens when I add further models like `Comment` or `Author` that need full sets of all their own Model Events? Will the single `boot()` function of `EventServiceProvider` just be absolutely huge?
- What is the purpose of [Laravel's 'other' Events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events)? Why would I ever need to use them if realistically my events will only respond to Model CRUD actions?

I am a beginner at Laravel, having come from CodeIgniter, so trying to wrap my head around the proper Laravel way of doing things. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Recently I came to same problem in one of my Laravel 5 project, where I had to log all Model Events. I decided to use `Traits`. I created `ModelEventLogger` Trait and simply used in all Model class which needed to be logged. I am going to change it as per your need Which is given below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

/**
 * Class ModelEventThrower 
 * @package App\Traits
 *
 *  Automatically throw Add, Update, Delete events of Model.
 */
trait ModelEventThrower {

    /**
     * Automatically boot with Model, and register Events handler.
     */
    protected static function bootModelEventThrower()
    {
        foreach (static::getModelEvents() as $eventName) {
            static::$eventName(function (Model $model) use ($eventName) {
                try {
                    $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($model);
                    Event::fire(strtolower($reflect->getShortName()).'.'.$eventName, $model);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the default events to be recorded if the $recordEvents
     * property does not exist on the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function getModelEvents()
    {
        if (isset(static::$recordEvents)) {
            return static::$recordEvents;
        }

        return [
            'created',
            'updated',
            'deleted',
        ];
    }
}
```

Now you can use this trait in any Model you want to throw events for. In your case in `Article` Model.

```
<?php namespace App;

use App\Traits\ModelEventThrower;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model {

    use ModelEventThrower;

    //Just in case you want specific events to be fired for Article model
    //uncomment following line of code

   // protected static $recordEvents = ['created'];

}
```

Now in your `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`, in `boot()` method register Event Handler for `Article`.

```
 public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
 {
     parent::boot($events);
     $events->subscribe('App\Handlers\Events\ArticleEventHandler');
 }
```

Now create Class `ArticleEventHandler` under `app/Handlers/Events` directory as below,

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Article;

class ArticleEventHandler{

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return \App\Handlers\Events\ArticleEventHandler
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
    * Handle article.created event
    */

   public function created(Article $article)
   {
      //Implement logic
   }

   /**
   * Handle article.updated event
   */

   public function updated(Article $article)
   {
      //Implement logic
   }

  /**
  * Handle article.deleted event
  */

  public function deleted(Article $article)
  {
     //Implement logic
  }

 /**
 * @param $events
 */
 public function subscribe($events)
 {
     $events->listen('article.created',
            'App\Handlers\Events\ArticleEventHandler@created');
     $events->listen('article.updated',
            'App\Handlers\Events\ArticleEventHandler@updated');
     $events->listen('article.deleted',
            'App\Handlers\Events\ArticleEventHandler@deleted');
 }

}
```

As you can see from different answers, from different Users, there are more than 1 way of handling Model Events. There are also Custom events That can be created in Events folder and can be handled in Handler folder and can be dispatched from different places. I hope it helps.

Comment: I think you can safely move the `$reflect = new \ReflectionClass($model);` in `bootModelEventThrower()` outside the `foreach` passing `static::class` instead of `$model`. You could also get the short name with `substr(static::class, strrpos(static::class, '\\') + 1)`.

Comment: @pinkel-vansia elegant way to generate generic model events. I also agree on @renocor, I used `function (Model $model) use ($reflect, $eventName)` though.

Comment: This thread is quite old, and the proposed solution is elegant :-)
But for those who want to log all Models events easily, I've recently used this great package that I recommend : https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog

Comment: In lara 6, to get a model name just use strtolower(class_basename(static::class)), no reflection needed

Answer (score 47):

In your case, you may also use following approach:

```
// Put this code in your Article Model

public static function boot() {

    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($article) {
        Event::fire('article.created', $article);
    });

    static::updated(function($article) {
        Event::fire('article.updated', $article);
    });

    static::deleted(function($article) {
        Event::fire('article.deleted', $article);
    });
}
```

Also, you need to register listeners in `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`:

```
protected $listen = [
    'article.created' => [
        'App\Handlers\Events\ArticleEvents@articleCreated',
    ],
    'article.updated' => [
        'App\Handlers\Events\ArticleEvents@articleUpdated',
    ],
    'article.deleted' => [
        'App\Handlers\Events\ArticleEvents@articleDeleted',
    ],
];
```

Also make sure you have created the handlers in `App\Handlers\Events` folder/directory to handle that event. For example, `article.created` handler could be like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Article;
use App\Services\Email\Mailer; // This one I use to email as a service class

class ArticleEvents {

    protected $mailer = null;

    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function articleCreated(Article $article)
    {
        // Implement mailer or use laravel mailer directly
        $this->mailer->notifyArticleCreated($article);
    }

    // Other Handlers/Methods...
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to modify my boot model for any reason, using the examples you gave to register the listener, I simply added the listener for created event in EventServiceProvider as follows `$listen = [
    'eloquent.created: '.User::class => [
        MyListener::class
    ]
];` That was it, I could listen to created event on User model. This is Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 9):

I found this the cleanest way to do what you want.

1.- Create an observer for the model (ArticleObserver)

```
use App\Article;

class ArticleObserver{

  public function __construct(Article $articles){
    $this->articles = $articles
  }

  public function created(Article $article){
    // Do anything you want to do, $article is the newly created article
  }

}
```

2.- Create a new ServiceProvider (ObserversServiceProvider), remember to add it to you config/app.php

```html
use App\Observers\ArticleObserver;
use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ObserversServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

  public function boot()
  {
    Article::observe($this->app->make(ArticleObserver::class));
  }

  public function register()
  {
    $this->app->bindShared(ArticleObserver::class, function()
        {
            return new ArticleObserver(new Article());
        });
  }

}
```

Comment: Why would you give a -1 to this answer after nearly 3 years?

This was at the time the prefered way to do this, and was taken from the official docs.

Answer (score 4):

You can opt for the Observer approach to deal with Model Events. For example, here is my `BaseObserver`:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Observers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class BaseObserver {

    public function saving(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function saved(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function updating(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function updated(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function creating(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function created(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function deleting(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function deleted(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function restoring(Eloquent $model) {}

    public function restored(Eloquent $model) {}
}
```

Now if I am to create a Product Model, its Observer would look like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Observers\BaseObserver;

class ProductObserver extends BaseObserver {

    public function creating(Eloquent $model)
    {
        $model->author_id = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    }

    public function created(Eloquent $model)
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('logo')) Image::make(Input::file('logo')->getRealPath())->save(public_path() ."/gfx/product/logo_{$model->id}.png");
    }

    public function updating(Eloquent $model)
    {
        $model->author_id = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    }

    public function updated(Eloquent $model)
    {
        if(Input::has('payment_types')) $model->paymentTypes()->attach(Input::get('payment_types'));

        //Upload logo
        $this->created($model);
    }
}
```

Regarding listeners, I create an `observers.php` file inside `Observers` dir and I include it from the `AppServiceProvider`. Here is a snippet from within the `observers.php` file:

```
<?php

\App\Models\Support\Ticket::observe(new \App\Observers\Support\TicketObserver);
\App\Models\Support\TicketReply::observe(new \App\Observers\Support\TicketReplyObserver);
```

All of this is regarding `Model Events`.

If you need to send an e-mail after a record is created, it would be cleaner to use the Laravel 'other' Events, as you will have a dedicated class to deal with just that, and fire it, when you wish, from the Controller.

The 'other' Events will have much more purpose as the more automated your app becomes, think of all the daily cronjobs you will need at some point. There will be no more cleaner way to deal with that other than 'other' Events.

Answer (score 3):

You've tagged this question as Laravel 5, so I would suggest not using model events as you'll end up with lots of extra code in your models which may make things difficult to manage in future. Instead, my recommendation would be to make use of the command bus and events.

Here's the docs for those features:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events

My recommendation would be to use the following pattern.

- You create a form which submits to your controller.
- Your controller dispatches the data from the request generated to a command.
- Your command does the heavy lifting - i.e. creates an entry in the database.
- Your command then fires an event which *can* be picked up by an event handler.
- Your event handler does something like send an email or update something else.

There are a few reasons why I like this pattern: Conceptually your commands handle things that are happening right now and events handle things that have just happened. Also, you can easily put command and event handlers onto a queue to be processed later on - this is great for sending emails as you tend not to want to do that in real time as they slow the HTTP request down a fair bit. You can also have multiple event handlers for a single event which is great for separating concerns.

It would be difficult to provide any actual code here as your question more about the concepts of Laravel, so I'd recommend viewing these videos so you get a good idea of how this pattern works:

This one describes the command bus:

https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-5-events

This one describes how events work:

https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-5-commands

Comment: Bus doesn't exist anymore for 5.1. Laravel changes too much. What would be the approach in 5.1 or 5.2?

Comment: It still exists, commands are just called queued jobs now. They don't have to run on the queue though, they can just run synchronously.

Comment: you bring up the good point of non-blocking events but this would make your insert non-blocking as well if you queued it. Events themselves should be non-blocking. I think everyone got  a bit over excited about Commands and Services for a second with Laravel...they're useful but necessarily just for adding an event

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple listeners on an event. So you may have a listener that sends an email when an article is updated, but you could have a totally different listener that does something totally different—they’ll both be executed.

Answer (score 1):

1) You may create an event listener for each new Model (ArticleEventSubscriber,CommentEventSubscriber) at boot method:

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    $events->subscribe('App\Listeners\ArticleEventListener');
    $events->subscribe('App\Listeners\CommentEventListener');
}
```

or you may also use `$subscribe` property

```
protected $subscribe = [
        'App\Listeners\ArticleEventListener',
        'App\Listeners\CommentEventListener',
    ];
```

There are many ways to listen and handle events. Take a look to current master documentation for discovering more ways(like usings closures) to do so : [Laravel Docs (master)](http://laravel.com/docs/master/events) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336337/laravel-5-confusion-between-event-handlers-and-listeners/30348451#30348451)

2) Model events are just events provided by default by Eloquent.

https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/491d58b5cc4149fa73cf93d499efb292cd11c88d/Eloquent/Model.php#L1171

https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/491d58b5cc4149fa73cf93d499efb292cd11c88d/Eloquent/Model.php#L1273

Answer (score 0):

I might come after the battle, but If you do not want all the fuss of extending classes or creating traits, you might want to give a try to this file exploration solution.

**Laravel 5.X solution**

**Beware the folder you choose to fetch the models should only contain models to make this solution to work**

**Do not forget to add the `use File`**

*app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use File;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $model_location = base_path() . '/app'; // Change to wherever your models are located at
        $files = File::files( $model_location );

        foreach( $files as $data ) {
            $model_name = "App\\" . pathinfo($data)['filename'];

            $model_name::creating(function($model) {
                // ...  
            });

            $model_name::created(function($model) {
                // ...  
            });

            $model_name::updating(function($model) {
                // ...  
            });

            $model_name::updated(function($model) {
                // ...  
            });

            $model_name::deleting(function($model) {
                // ...  
            });

            $model_name::deleted(function($model) {
                // ...  
            });

            $model_name::saving(function($model) {
                // ...  
            });

            $model_name::saved(function($model) {
                // ...  
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you write the less code possible!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 6, the shortest solution

**BaseSubscriber** class

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/**
 * Class BaseSubscriber
 * @package App\Listeners
 */
abstract class BaseSubscriber
{

    /**
     * Returns the first part of an event name (before the first dot)
     * Can be a class namespace
     * @return string
     */
    protected abstract function getEventSubject(): string;

    /**
     * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
     * @param Dispatcher $events
     */
    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $currentNamespace = get_class($this);
        $eventSubject = strtolower(class_basename($this->getEventSubject()));

        foreach (get_class_methods($this) as $method) {
            if (Str::startsWith($method, 'handle')) {
                $suffix = strtolower(Str::after($method, 'handle'));
                $events->listen("$eventSubject.$suffix", "$currentNamespace@$method");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**OrderEventSubscriber** class. Handlers for **Order** model events

```
use App\Models\Order;

/**
 * Class OrderEventSubscriber
 * @package App\Listeners
 */
class OrderEventSubscriber extends BaseSubscriber
{

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getEventSubject(): string
    {
        return Order::class; // Or just 'order'
    }

    /**
     * @param Order $order
     */
    public function handleSaved(Order $order)
    {
      // Handle 'saved' event
    }

    /**
     * @param Order $order
     */
    public function handleCreating(Order $order)
    {
       // Handle 'creating' event
    }

}
```

**ModelEvents** trait. It goes to your models, in my case - App\Model\Order

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Trait ModelEvents
 * @package App\Traits
 */
trait ModelEvents
{

    /**
     * Register model events
     */
    protected static function bootModelEvents()
    {
        foreach (static::registerModelEvents() as $eventName) {
            static::$eventName(function (Model $model) use ($eventName) {
                event(strtolower(class_basename(static::class)) . ".$eventName", $model);
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array of default registered model events
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function registerModelEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'created',
            'updated',
            'deleted',
        ];
    }
}
```

Register the subscriber in a service provider, e.g **AppServiceProvider**

```
/**
 * @param Dispatcher $events
 */
public function boot(Dispatcher $events)
{
    $events->subscribe(OrderEventSubscriber::class);
}
```

How just add the **ModelEvents** trait into your model, adjust the events you want to register instead of default ones:

```
protected static function registerModelEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'creating',
            'saved',
        ];
    }
```

Done!