# Laravel 5 - Confusion between Event Handlers and Listeners

Tags: laravel, event-handling, laravel-5, event-listener

I'm a bit confused about the different between **Events** and **Listeners**.

I understood how you can create your events under `Events` then register them and implement the Handlers in `Handlers\Events`. So here I have events and the handling of events.

They work after I define them in `Providers\EventServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $listen = [
    UserHasSignedUp::class => [
        SendWelcomeEmail::class,
        SendAdminEmail::class
    ]
];
```

So what are **Listeners**?

To me they seem exactly the same thing as **Event Handlers**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your example `UserHasSignedUp` is an `Event`. `SendWelcomeEmail` and `SendAdminEmail` are two listeners "waiting" for the event UserHasSignedUp to be fired and they should implement the required business logic at `handle` method of each one.

Super simple example:

Somewhere in UserController

```
Event::fire(new UserHasSignedUp($user)); //UserHasSignedUp is the event being fired
```

SendWelcomeEmail class

```
class SendWelcomeEmail //this is the listener class
{
    public function handle(UserHasSignedUp $event) //this is the "handler method"
    {
        //send an email
    }   
}
```

As you can see, each event can have multiple listeners, but a listener can't listen to more than a single event.
If you want a class listening to many events, you should take a look to [Event Subscribers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events#event-subscribers)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah I think I had confused myself because I had created a Listeners folder but that's not actually part of Laravel 5 that's why I didn't understand difference between /Handlers/Events and /Listeners

Comment: ah i see! hope my answer helped =)

Comment: Hi Ezequiel, one more question I got a bit more confused as I saw the video from Laracon (october 2014) where they use the event ->raise and event ->release method, is this still the way to do it or has this been changed since?  https://youtu.be/2_380DKU93U?t=2034

Comment: This does not address the question. In laravel Event Handlers and Event Listeners are 2 separate things. just check `php artisan list` and see that you can use artisan to generate either. The question (and what I cannot find on the internet for the life of me) is what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between them seems to be is, `handler:event` is from Laravel 5.0's folder structure, and `make:listener` is the **new & current** folder structure. **Functionally, they are the same**! - [Upgrade Guide to Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0)

> **Commands & Handlers**
>
> The app/Commands directory has been renamed to
>   app/Jobs. However, you are not required to move all of your commands
>   to the new location, and you may continue using the make:command and
>   handler:command Artisan commands to generate your classes.
>
> Likewise, ***the app/Handlers directory has been renamed to app/Listeners***
>   and now only contains event listeners. However, you are not required
>   to move or rename your existing command and event handlers, and you
>   may continue to use the handler:event command to generate event
>   handlers.
>
> By providing backwards compatibility for the Laravel 5.0 folder
>   structure, you may upgrade your applications to Laravel 5.1 and slowly
>   upgrade your events and commands to their new locations when it is
>   convenient for you or your team.

It's just the backward compatibility provided in Laravel 5.1. In other words, earlier, Jobs/Commands/Listeners were **not self-handling**, now **they are**.

**Note that**, `handler:event` is not available **after Laravel 5.1**.

Answer (score 0):

There's not too much information on this out there, so this might just be speculation. I took a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNYb1r4eMio) and saw that you can use handlers with commands. I think if you're using commands, that makes sense to have all your handlers in one spot. However if you're not, then having a `App\Handlers\Events\Whatever` might not be as desirable as `App\Listeners\Whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

Listeners vs. Handlers :

A listener `listen` for a specific event to be fired. xxxxCreatedListener will only listen for xxxx

A handler can handle multiple events to be fired. For exemple, let's say you use performing CRUD operations, your handler could wait for the xxxxCreatedEvent, xxxxDeletedEvent, xxxxUpdatedEvent.