# laravel 5.1 - trait boot not being called for model::update() function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have created trait as follows on this page app/Traits/ModelEventThrower.php

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Input;
use Event;
use App\Events\ActivityLog;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

/**
 * Class ModelEventThrower 
 * @package App\Traits
 *
 *  Automatically throw Add, Update, Delete events of Model.
 */
trait ModelEventThrower {

    /**
     * Automatically boot with Model, and register Events handler.
     */
    protected static function bootModelEventThrower()
    {

        foreach (static::getModelEvents() as $eventName) {

            static::$eventName(function (Model $model) use ($eventName) {
                try {

                    $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($model);

                    echo "here";exit;

                  } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the default events to be recorded if the $recordEvents
     * property does not exist on the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function getModelEvents()
    {
        if (isset(static::$recordEvents)) {
            return static::$recordEvents;
        }

        return [
            'created',
            'updated',
            'deleted',
        ];
    }
}
```

My City Model is something like this

```
namespace App;

use App\Traits\ModelEventThrower;
use App\Events\ActivityLog;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Event;

class City extends Model
{
    use ModelEventThrower;
    //protected static $recordEvents = ['updated'];
...
}
```

My CitiesController is

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\City;
use App\Country;
use Input;
use Validator;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CitiesController extends Controller
{
......
    public function update(City $city,Request $request)
    {
     ......
    $city->where('id','=',$input['id'])->update($input);
```

Somehow, I dont see its calling the function written in trait file. When I tried to create `$city->create($input);` it echos "here" and stops execusion, but not doing same for update function , however I could successfully update the records.

Any suggestion/help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to do as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30582174/4514022

Comment: I don't see where that function is being called.

Comment: use ModelEventThrower; in City model

Comment: Traits are really just a glorified copy and paste.  Just adding a `use` statement for it won't make any of it execute.  You need to call the method on it just like you would as though that method were in the class itself.

Comment: I know I made some mistake but not able to identify what and where, more ever I couldn't find out why create() function is getting called and why not update().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with `Laravel`. By adding a constructor in the model to call the `boot()` function of the parent `Model`, like so:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::boot();
}
```

you can make sure that all the traits are booted. This solved it for me.