# Implementing Laravel Eloquent Model Events - checking for fired events

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am following this answer:

[Laravel Model Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332117/laravel-model-events-im-a-bit-confused-about-where-theyre-meant-to-go)

And I'm trying to implement the code of the marked answer.

I think everythink is just as the "answer" but it doesnt seem to be firing the events.

How do I check if the events are firing?

This is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\ModelEventThrower;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cuotas extends Model
{
    use ModelEventThrower;


    protected $fillable = [ 'apartamento_id','fecha_cuota','fecha_vencimiento', 'tipo_cuota_id', 'monto', 'descripcion_cuota','saldo'  ];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at','fecha_vencimiento','fecha_cuota'];
    protected $appends = ['tipo_cuota'];

    //protected static $othersEvents = ['saving'];



    function getTipoCuotaAttribute(){
        $id = $this->attributes['tipo_cuota_id'];
        $tipoCuota = TipoCuota::lists('descripcion_cuota','id')->toArray();
        return $tipoCuota[$id];
    }


    function getFechaVencimientoAttribute($value){
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
    }
    function setFechaVencimientoAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['fecha_vencimiento'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
    }

    function getFechaCuotaAttribute($value){
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
    }
    function setFechaCuotaAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['fecha_cuota'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
    }

    function apartamento()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Apartamentos', 'apartamento_id');
    }
    public function pagos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pagos','cuota_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

This is my Trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

/**
 * Class ModelEventThrower
 * @package App\Traits
 *
 *  Automatically throw Add, Update, Delete events of Model.
 */
trait ModelEventThrower {

    /**
     * Automatically boot with Model, and register Events handler.
     */
    protected static function bootModelEventThrower()
    {

        foreach (static::getModelEvents() as $eventName) {
            static::$eventName(function (Model $model) use ($eventName) {
                try {
                    $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($model);
                    Event::fire(strtolower($reflect->getShortName()).'.'.$eventName, $model);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the default events to be recorded if the $recordEvents
     * property does not exist on the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function getModelEvents()
    {
        if (isset(static::$othersEvents)) {
            return static::$othersEvents;
        }

        return [
            'created',
            'updated',
            'deleted',
        ];
    }
}
```

My EventServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [ 'App\Listeners\EventListener', ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);
        $events->subscribe('App\Handlers\Events\CuotasEventHandler');
    }
}
```

My Event Handler:

```
<?php

namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Cuotas;

class CuotasEventHandler{

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return \App\Handlers\Events\CuotasEventHandler
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle cuotas.created event
     */

    public function created(Cuotas $cuotas)
    {
       dd('created');
    }

    /**
     * Handle cuotas.updated event
     */

    public function updated(Cuotas $cuotas)
    {
        //Implement logic
        dd('updated');
    }

    /**
     * Handle cuotas.deleted event
     */

    public function deleted(Cuotas $cuotas)
    {
        //Implement logic
        dd('deleted');
    }

    /**
     * @param $events
     */
    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen('cuotas.created','App\Handlers\Events\CuotasEventHandler@created');
        $events->listen('cuotas.updated','App\Handlers\Events\CuotasEventHandler@updated');
        $events->listen('cuotas.deleted','App\Handlers\Events\CuotasEventHandler@deleted');

    }

}
```

When i update, delete or create a new record in the model $Cuotas, i cant see if the event is getting fired.

My intention is to update the "saldo" (balance) column of the model using the payments already done in other model called "pagos".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how, the events start to fire by them self after I restart the server.