# Laravel - configure modellog

Tags: php, laravel-5, model

As we know, the model has 2/3 timestamps where it logs the 'created_at', 'updated_at' and 'deleted_at'. I want to add a 'who' method for this three timestanp where the model will log, that who created/updated/deleted that row.

Where I can add this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you need to use Laravel [Eloquent event listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events). By using these you can listen to various events of a Eloquent model i.e. create, update, delete and hook your respective actions you want to perform.

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into various points in the model's lifecycle using the following methods: creating, created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting,  deleted, restoring, restored. Events allow you to easily execute code each time a specific model class is saved or updated in the database.

If you need to listen to the events irrespective of the model this post might help you:

[Laravel Model Events - I'm a bit confused about where they're meant to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332117/laravel-model-events-im-a-bit-confused-about-where-theyre-meant-to-go)

Hope it would help.

Comment: Thank you. And do I need to make these "listeners" separatedly, or do I have a "wildcard" method, too? For example do I need to make the "if I delete an user than paste my user id next to it" and "if I delete this event paste my user id next to it", too, or I only make the "if I delete something paste my user id next to it"?

Comment: Actually it depends on your use case. If the  method of pasting user id is common for all models you would use the second example or if it varies as per model definition you should use first example and listen to the event for every model separately.