# Dispatching events from an extended class

Tags: php, laravel, events

In a Laravel 5.5 project, I have a Person class and a Student class. The Student class extends the Person class. I have a bunch of stuff that needs to happen when a new person is created and a bunch of stuff that needs to happen when a new student (who is also a person of course) is created.

My classes look something like this...

```
class Person extends Model {
        protected $dispatchesEvents = [
            'created' => PersonJoins::class
        ];}
```

.

```
class Student extends Person {    
        protected $dispatchesEvents = [
            'created' => StudentIsCreated::class,
        ];}
```

When a new Student instance is created, the StudentIsCreated event fires but the PersonJoins event does not.

A workaround is to change the 'created' in one of the models to 'saved' and then both events are triggered. From that, it seems obvious what is happening. The 'created' element in the $dispatchesEvents array on the Person model is being overwritten by the same on the Student model. Even just typing that, it seems the solution should be obvious but I just can't see it.

So, my question is this... How do I have an event triggered by 'created' on two models, one of which extends the other?

Thank you.
David.

**EDIT:**
After reading @hdifen answer. My Student model now looks like this...

```
class Student extends Person
{
  protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::created(function($student) {
            \Event::Fire('StudentCreated', $student);
    });
}
```

}

and in `App\Events\StudentCreated.php` I have...

```
class StudentCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($student)
    {
        echo ("\r\nStudentCreated event has fired");
        $this->student = $student;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('Student-Is-Created-Channel');
    }
}
```

But the event doesn't seem to be fired. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how are you making the distinction between these two models on your database?

Comment: @GaimZz
There isn't a Person table on the database. The Person class is just used to take care of things that apply to all types of users (Students and Staff currently).

The plan is, when a person is created whether Student or Staff, the PersonJoins event creates a User. When a student is created, as well as the User being created because Student extends Person, I want the StudentIsCreated event to trigger which will create a new instance of the Grades model for example.

Comment: As per laravel documentation explains, Laravel events are binded to only 1 model, so If I was you I'd either re-think your architecture or go with the 'save' event workaround

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct the student model is overwriting the parent variable $dispatchesEvents.

I would recommend not using `$dispatchedEvent` as events are mainly used if you are doing something more complex that requires other parts of your code to react when they are fired.

The simple solution is to just manually hook into the created event in your model, in your case you want to create a grades model when a student is created?

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::created(function($model) {
        $grade = new Grade;
        $model->grades->save($grade);
        // Or if you really want to use an event something like
        Event::fire('student.created', $student);
    });
}
```

This post might give you an idea:

[Laravel Model Events - I'm a bit confused about where they're meant to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332117/laravel-model-events-im-a-bit-confused-about-where-theyre-meant-to-go).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if Event:fire still works in Laravel 5.5? It doesn't seem to be firing the event for me. I want to use events still as the creating of a grades model was just an example. Lots more things will happen when a student is created.